# How do I test Stripe Express manual payouts in the test mode?

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am working on a project which is a simple hirer-worker platform. I have used manual payouts to hold connected account balance. I wanted to test the payout after a worker has certain amount of balance in his connected account. But the balance shows up on **Available Soon**. I read the docs and it said that it requires 7-14 days for the first payout. Do I have to wait that long even in the test mode ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stripe provide test card numbers in their [documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards) that let you reproduce various flows such as specific card brand or card's country. They have a dedicated [sub-section](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards-responses) where they recommend using the card `4000000000000077` or its equivalent `pm_card_bypassPending` to create a payment that makes the funds immediately available in Test mode. This should allow you to test this flow on your connected accounts!

Comment: I totally missed that sub section. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

this code will charge your amount in Stripe immediately by using the property of source and its value is  "tok_bypassPending" ,it will make the available amount be activated..

```
 const charge = await stripe.charges.create({
amount: 200000,
currency: "eur",
source: "tok_bypassPending",
description:
  "My First Test Charge (created for API docs at 
https://www.stripe.com/docs/api)",
});
```

for more, this is the link to stripe docs...
https://stripe.com/docs/testing?numbers-or-method-or-token=tokens#refunds